# Passing date value from objective C to Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios5

I am trying to pass a array of date values from Objective C to Javascript.
I tried to pass it this way -

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"01-03",@"01-05",@"01-07",@"01-09",@"01-11", nil];
self.dateString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[wtWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName([%@])", dateString]];
```

In my Javascript -

```
<script>
function methodName(val,val1)
   {
      alert(val1);
   }
</script>
```

However, what happens here is that the value get displayed as -2, -4, -6, -8, -10 . It literally does a subtraction operation on the values.

Would someone be able to help me out with how I can get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Obj-C snippet:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName([%@])", dateString]
```

creates the following string:

```
methodName(01-03,01-05,01-07,01-09,01-11)
```

which in Javascript is a bunch of subtraction operations.  If you want to use -stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, you need to escape the dates somehow:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"'01-03'",@"'01-05'",@"'01-07'",@"'01-09'",@"'01-11'", nil];
self.dateString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
[wtWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName([%@])", dateString]];
```

or:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"01-03",@"01-05",@"01-07",@"01-09",@"01-11", nil];
self.dateString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"','"];
[wtWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName(['%@'])", dateString]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your strings in single quotes:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"'01-03'",@"'01-05'",@"'01-07'",@"'01-09'",@"'01-11'", nil];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but that did not work for some reason.. @iccir's answer here helped though..